# Clone element via insertAdjacentElement instead of "cutting" it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to clone an element into a new position in the DOM. I'm using `insertAdjacentElement` but that only seems to "cut and paste" it into a new location. Is it possible to clone the element instead?

```js
document.getElementById('subNav').insertAdjacentElement(
  'afterbegin', 
  document.getElementById('main_0_columnb_0_PanelMenu')
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy and paste html elements using the `cloneNode` method like this:

```
document.getElementById('subNav').insertAdjacentElement(
    'afterbegin', 
    document.getElementById('main_0_columnb_0_PanelMenu').cloneNode(true)
);
```

For further reading, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). The argument passed to `cloneNode` indicates whether to copy just node (shallow copy) or node with children (deep copy). `true` represents deep copy.